# How can I configure an alert for when a logic app workflow (standard) fails

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am trying to configure an alert for when a workflow in Logic app Standard fails.However, I cannot find any out-of-the-box Metric/Signal similar to "RunsFailed" that is available for Logic App Consumption.

Another way is to raise alerts based on Log Analytics Workspace but that would require me to write custom logs in case of an error.

[image: This is where I am looking for a correct signal to add in my Alert condition]

Answer (score 2):

**Http 404 at Logic Apps Standard** Model/Type with workflow type('***Stateful***'), is more similar to **'Runs failed' Metric of Logic Apps Consumption** Model/Type.
Have created and unit-tested with the alerts based on alert rule set-ups and both works similar.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it as well and it works.

Comment: Glad to know it helped you. Can you please mark this as an answer

Comment: @Arulmouzhi, I have noticed that the alert is triggered when the workflow is Successful as well - it happens when the retry on on singe action is enabled. If an action is successful  after a few attempt the the alert is triggered as well. Do you have any idea how to handle this case?